# What operation does this algorithm do on graphs?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, directed-graphs

I have to find the solution that this algorithm gives about graphs, knowing that the Graph is given by $ G = (V, E) $, with arcs labeled by $ w $ and that $ G $ \ $ e $ indicates that the arc $ e $ of the graph. I mean $ G $\ $ e $ is the elgraph with vertices $ V $ and arcs $ E $ \ {e}. Being $ V_G $ for the vertices of $ G $ and $ E_G $ for its arcs, and that the graph is connected.

I understand that the first line orders the values of $ w $ in decreasing order, then it goes through the arcs, but after the if condition I don't understand what the next line does, G $ \leftarrow $ $ G $ \ $ e $.

[image: Algorithm]

Comment: What algorithm are you referring to? What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It goes through the edges in order of decreasing weight. If removing an edge would disconnect the graph, that edge is kept; otherwise, it is deleted. When the algorithm is done, what’s left is a spanning tree for $G$.

To see this, let $G'$ be the graph that is returned by the algorithm. Clearly $G'$ is connected: the algorithm never removes an edge whose removal would disconnect the graph. Suppose that $G'$ contained a cycle $C$. Let $e$ be the first edge of $C$ in the sorted list produced by the first line of the algorithm. When the algorithm reached $e$ in the **for** loop, all of the edges of $C$ were still in the graph, so removing $e$ would not have disconnected the graph, and therefore $e$ would have been removed. Thus, $G'$ cannot contain a cycle. Being connected and acyclic, $G'$ is a tree and hence a spanning tree for $G$.

Answer (score 1):

The backwards arrow in algorithms often represents an assignment, meaning, store the graph $G$ with edge $e$ removed in the variable for $G$. So now we have updated $G$ to remove edge $e$.

Comment: So the function of the algorithm is to update the graph?

Comment: @JohanC: It does a lot more than that: see my answer.